# "Села батарейка на аппарате..." - таки "на"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Ребят, я ничем батареечным не пользуюсь и при мне никто не говорил про батарейки на чём-либо...

Как же ж жить?! О_о

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это аппарат **на** батарейке (на каком источнике энергии работает?), а батарейка **в** аппарате: по месту расположения она **внутри** - разве что она случайно какая-нибудь пристяжная или навесная.

Comment: Спасибо за доходчивое разъяснение!